# Is there a way to vectorize two arrays pointing at each other in NumPy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

For all the folks who rock at vectorizing loops: I have two NumPy arrays of shape `(N,)` that contain indices to each other. Say we have `a = np.asarray([0, 1, 2])` and `b = np.array([1, 2, np.nan])`. The function should first look at `a[0]` to get `0`, then do `b[0]` to get `1`, then again `a[1]` to get `2`, and so on until we get `np.nan`. So the function is simply `a[b[a[b[a[0]]]]] = np.nan`. The output should contain two lists of values that were called for `a` and `b` respectively. Indices in `b` are always greater than in `a`, such that the process cannot get stuck.

I wrote a simple function that can do just this (wrapped with numba - 18.2 µs):

```
a = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
b = np.array([ 2.,  3.,  4., nan, nan])

lst = []
while True:
    if len(lst) > 0:
        idx = lst[-1]
    else:
        idx = 0
    if len(lst) % 2 == 0:
        if idx < len(a) - 1:
            next_idx = a[idx]
            if np.isnan(next_idx):
                break
            lst.append(int(next_idx))
        else:
            break
    else:
        if idx < len(b) - 1:
            next_idx = b[idx]
            if np.isnan(next_idx):
                break
            lst.append(int(next_idx))
        else:
            break
```

The first list is `lst[::2]`:

```
[0, 2]
```

The second is `lst[1::2]`:

```
[2, 4]
```

Any way to vectorize this? Both arrays in inputs as well as both lists in output always have the same shape.

Comment: This seems difficult to vectorize... and even then I'm not sure it would be faster than a well optimized Numba loop... but in any case, are inputs such that the number of "steps" in the result is always the same? And, is `np.nan` always in the second list? Btw, if you are storing `np.nan` in the array it will have to be float, which is not the best type for indexing... maybe you could consider using `-1` or something else as "end marker" instead.

Comment: The non-vectorized solution can of course be tweaked further, as shown by your answer. What I'm trying to achieve is to avoid loops (and recursion) altogether. This problem is part of a bigger problem I'm currently facing: having time series data, one has to generate two types of signals one after another using some function. I've found a way to vectorize finding one type of signals if another one has already been defined. But if both are undefined, then the solution seems to be only iterative.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a vectorized solution, but as a Numba solution it should be quite faster, and simpler. I changed the code slightly to use integers and `-1` instead of `np.nan`, it is trivial to switch to this representation with something like `b = np.where(np.isnan(b), -1, b)`, and it makes the code more efficient. Instead of having a growing structure within the Numba function, I preallocate the output array in advance, so the loop can run much faster.

```py
import numba as nb

def point_each_other(a, b):
    # Convert inputs to array if they are not already
    a = np.asarray(a)
    b = np.asarray(b)
    # Make output array in advance
    out = np.empty(len(a) + len(b), dtype=a.dtype)
    # Call Numba function
    n = point_each_other_nb(a, b, out)
    # Return relevan part of the output
    return out[:n]

@nb.njit
def point_each_other_nb(a, b, out):
    curr = 0
    i = 0
    while curr >= 0:
        # You can do bad input checking with the following
        # if i >= len(out):
        #     raise ValueError
        # Save current index
        out[i] = curr
        # Get the next index
        curr = a[curr]
        # Swap arrays
        a, b = b, a
        # Advance counter
        i += 1
    # Return number of stored indices
    return i - 1

# Test
a = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
b = np.array([2, 3, 4, -1, -1])
out = point_each_other(a, b)
print(out[::2])
# [0 2 4]
print(out[1::2])
# [0 2]
```

Comment: Your solution produces the same inputs as mine if using `out[1:n]` and is also faster, thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

Not vectorized, but here's recursive solution:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([0,1,2,3,4])
b = np.array([2,3,4,np.nan, np.nan])

def rec(i,b,a, a_out, b_out):
    if np.isnan(b[i]): return
    else:
        if not np.isnan(b[i]): a_out.append(i)
        rec(int(b[i]), a, b, b_out, a_out)
    return a_out, b_out

print(rec(0,b,a,[],[]))
```

**Output**

```
([0, 2], [2, 4])
```